# ¿Cómo sería esta instrucción en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

Quiero escribir la siguiente sentencia en MySQL:

**SQL Server** `set @cont = (select MAX(id_fact) from factura)`

Estoy haciendo un procedure en el que necesito asignarle el valor más alto del `id` a la variable `cont`.

Había intentado poner primero el `SELECT`  y luego el `SET` , obviamente no obtuve el resultado deseado.

De esta forma:

```
 SELECT * FROM facturas;
 SET cont= max(id_facturas);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después del `SELECT` se hace la asignación con un `INTO`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `contador`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE cont INT;
  SELECT MAX(id_fact) INTO cont FROM factura;
  SELECT cont;
END
```

A llamar a `contador()` obtenemos:

```
+------+
| cont |
+------+
|    9 |
+------+
```

el cual coincide con el `id_fact` más grande en mi base de datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió la explicación